# Vector bundles on $M/G$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $M$ be an algebraic variety with an action of algebraic group $G$, and $V$ be a linear representation of $G$. Then one can consider the set $E = (M \times V) / G$. If there is a quotient space $M/G$, the one gets the $G$-equivariant morphism $E \to M/G$. When is $E$ a vector bundle over $M/G$ and is the structure of vector bundle on it unique?

Comment: One special case is that when the action of $G$ on $M$ is free, $E\rightarrow M/G$ is a vector bundle with fiber $V$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Kempf's lemma**, see theorem 2.3 of [Narasimhan, Drezet *Groupe de Picard des variétés de modules de fibrés semi-stables sur les courbes algébriques.*](http://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/dms/load/img/?PID=GDZPPN002106469&physid=PHYS_0069) and proposition 4.2 of [Knop, Kraft, Vust *The Picard group of a $G$-Variety*](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.114.2496&rep=rep1&type=pdf):

Let a reductive algebraic group $G$ act on an irreducible algebraic variety $X$, and let $\pi: X \to X//G$ be a good quotient (e.g., a geometric quotient), then the morphism
$$\pi^*: \operatorname{Vect}(X//G) \to \operatorname{Vect}_G(X)$$
from vector bundles $X//G$ to $G$-equivariant vector bundles is injective (see also [MO:243655](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/243649/uniqueness-of-descent/#243655)) and the image consists of $G$-equivariant vector bundles $E$ such that for every closed point $x \in X$ with closed $G$-orbit the stabilizer subgroup $G_x$ acts trivially on the fiber $E_x$.

So, if $G$ acts freely on $X$, then every $G$-equivariant vector bundle descends. In particular, this applies to the trivial bundle $X \times V$ with an action of $G$ induced from actions on $X$ and $V$.

Comment: Taken mainly from answer [MO:251265](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/251265) by abx. Thank you!